# Gatsby Content Sync points to wrong page

Tags: gatsby, strapi, gatsby-cloud

I am using Gatsby with Strapi and all the previews are triggered by [@strapi/plugin-gatsby-preview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@strapi/plugin-gatsby-preview)

In one of the collection types I have a small problem, the preview button when I click it - opens up a wrong page.
It points to one of the programmes (the single programme page), where it should actually point to a dynamic page set (listing page for those programmes).

I went through the documentation and this is what it says:

*"In the case that your content lives on multiple pages, for example a blog post page and a blog listing page, and you find you’re being routed to the page you don’t want to view your preview on, you can specify which node owns which page using the [ownerNodeId setting in the createPage API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions#createPage). Set the ownerNodeId to the Gatsby node.id of the node you want to preview for the page. Note that the ownerNodeId must correspond to the node.id of a node which is queried on that page via a GraphQL query."*

I have tried to do that and I did this - for each dynamic page set (listing page), and for each programme inside of it (single programme page) I create a page, I pass the ownerNodeId to the nested loop but it still doesn't work.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
  data.allStrapiDynamicPageSet.edges.forEach(({ node: { id, strapi_id, pageSlug, location, programmes } }) => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: `dynamic-page-set/${strapi_id}`,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/dynamic-page-sets-listing.js"),
      context: {
        id: id,
      },
    });
    programmes.forEach((prog) => {
      actions.createPage({
        path: `i/${prog.progSlug}/${pageSlug}`,
        component: path.resolve("./src/templates/dynamic-page-set.js"),
        ownerNodeId: id,
        context: {
          id: id,
          progId: prog.id,
          type: "DYNAMIC_PAGE_SET",
          ProgrammeName: pageSlug,
          degreeId: prog?.degree_level?.id,
          locationId: location?.id,
        },
      });
    });
  });
```